# How to create images with Xamarin Forms mobile app?

Tags: c#, xaml, bitmap

I am trying to create and save an image using Xamarin Forms on a mobile app. I tried doing what I did below and running it on a pixel emulator although I got an alert that said: "Operation is not supported on this platform." After testing it, I found the issue was using System.Drawing.Bitmap, is there another way I can create an image?

```
public static void OutputZoomedPicture(Pixel[,] picture)
    {
        int p = 0;
        int[] pixels = new int[(w - p) * (h - p)];

        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(w-p, h-p);

        for (int i = 0; i < h - p; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < w - p; j++)
            {
                pixels[i * (w - p) + j] = picture[i, j].GetColorInt();

                bmp.SetPixel(i, j, ColorConverters.FromUInt(Convert.ToUInt32(picture[i,j].GetColorInt())));

            }
        }
        bmp.Save("D:\\Image\\Mandelbrot.png");

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at `SKCanvas` which allows you to 'draw' on a canvas which can then be displayed onscreen or saved.

Comment: Thanks Neil, that worked!